# Connecting to mysql using Sequel on Openshift

Tags: mysql, ruby, openshift, sequel

I'm developing a site using Cloud9 with Ruby and Sinatra and I'm deploying to Openshift. I have set up cartridges for mySQL and PhpMyAdmin. The problem I'm having is connecting to the database using Sequel.

Here's what I have

```
DBS = Sequel.connect('mysql://OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD@OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT')
heros = DBS[:superheros]
get '/mysql' do
  "#{heros.first[:name]}"
  #"mysql"
end
```

I've also tried

```
db_user = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']
db_pass = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']
db_host = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']
db_port = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']
DBS = Sequel.connect('mysql://#{db_user}:#{db_pass}@#{db_host}/#{db_port}')
```

All I'm getting back is Internal Server Error

Can anyone please provide me with some tips on how I can connect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DBS = Sequel.connect('mysql://#{db_user}:#{db_pass}@#{db_host}/#{db_port}')
```

[How to connect to DB with Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html)

1. Port and host are separated via "/", but should be ":" (colon)
2. You forgot database name.

Example of correct connection string:

```
mysql://user:password@host:port/database
```

Try something like that

```
db_user = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']  
db_pass = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']  
db_host = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']  
db_port = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']  
db_name = ENV['OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME']  
DBS = Sequel.connect('mysql://#{db_user}:#{db_pass}@#{db_host}:#{db_port}/#{db_name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I tried all sorts of permutations but in the end this worked

```
db_user = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']
db_pass = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD']
db_host = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']
db_port = ENV['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']
DBS = Sequel.connect(:adapter=>'mysql', :host=>db_host, :database=>"prescreen", :user=>db_user, :password=>db_pass)
```